# Check redirect request or not

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there any way to check in my controller's method that I got plain HTTP GET/POST but not redirected request from another controller?

For instance I have

```
@Controller  
public class A {

    @RequestMapping("page1")
    public String loadPage(final Model model) {
    {           
         // SHOULD CHECK HERE WAS IT INVOKED FROM CLASS' B 'loadPage' METHOD 
         // OR DIRECTLY BY USER
         if (!model.containsAttribute("myForm"))
         {
             model.addAttribute("myForm", new MyForm());
         }
         return "view1";
    }
}

@Controller
public class B {

    @RequestMapping("page2")
    public String loadPage(final Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
        // ... 
        // populate form here with some values
        // myForm.setEntries(...);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("myForm", myForm);
        return "redirect:page1";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** To prove question actuality please see updated code snippet with **flashAttributes** and check for existence at Model for the form DTO. As you can see **myForm** attributes may not be added to Model since it it existed there already - this approach is performed due to ability to show already fulfilled **MyForm** in case of request on **loadPage** from **Controller B**.

Comment: Why do you care? If the method should do something else than what it does when the request doesn't come from a redirect, then it should simply be another method: single responsibility principle.

Comment: Please see my update. I've added some core code that may change your opinion regarding this question importance.

Comment: With your code update it work's like you expected isn't it?